# opinin mining using naive bayes classifier

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I am working an classifying tweets as positive or negative opinion. I heard Naive Bayes classifier is used commonly for classifying and I would like to write my own Naive Bayes Classifier for my project. Since, I am new to Data Mining and Naive Bayes classifier am not able to understand what and how to use Naive Bayes. Can anyone help me through??

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a classifier needs to be trained with already classified data, the more the better; for example you need one hundred positive tweets and another one hundred negative.

If you're using python, you could start with [NLTK](http://nltk.org/) and its huge collection of [corpora](http://www.nltk.org/data.html)

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098533/implementing-bag-of-words-naive-bayes-classifier-in-nltk) for a practical example.

Comment: it's merely a personal choice, also depending on your actual know-how.
If you already use java, I'd suggest the great [Stanford University CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml), entirely written in java; on the other hand, with python you could start with [NLTK](http://nltk.org/) or [pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pattern).

In my case, I preferred python over java (also because it's an interpreted language)